# How to transpose a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples, transpose, nested-lists

Let **ll** be a list of lists, and **tt** a tuple of tuples

**Input**: ll = `[["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]`

**Desired output:** tt = `(("a1","b1","c1"),("a2","b2","c2"))`

I have managed to solve it for a list of **two-element lists**, meaning that the internal list only contained two elements each.

```
def list_of_list_to_tuple_of_tuple(ll):
    first_elements = [i[0] for i in ll]
    second_elements = [i[1] for i in ll]
    
    new_list = []
    new_list.append(tuple(first_elements))
    new_list.append(tuple(second_elements))
    return tuple(new_list)

ll = [["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]
list_of_list_to_tuple_of_tuple(ll)
```

Now, the questions are:

1. Is there any other method to easily accomplish what I have done?
2. Is there any method to easily generalize this algorithm if we have a list of **3 internal lists** and each **internal list containing n elements?** For example:

**Input:** ll = `[["a1","a2","a3",..."an"],["b1","b2","b3",..."bn"],["c1","c2","c3",..."cn"]]`

**Desired Output:** tt = `(("a1","b1","c1"),("a2","b2","c2"),("a3","b3","c3"),...,("an","bn","cn"))`

Comment: just do this `tuple(zip(*l))`. More details in my answer.

Comment: Regarding your function: its argument is called `list_`, but then you refer to `ll` instead. That's a mistake

Comment: Also note you can write directly `result = (tuple(x[0] for x in ll), tuple(x[1] for x in ll))` rather than all these intermediate steps with `newlist.append`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one-liner -

```
tuple(zip(*l))
```

#### Example 1

```
l = [["a1","a2"],
     ["b1","b2"],
     ["c1","c2"]]

tuple(zip(*l))
```

```
(('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), 
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'))
```

##### Example 2

```
l2 = [["a1","a2","a3","an"],
      ["b1","b2","b3","bn"],
      ["c1","c2","c3","cn"]]

tuple(zip(*l2))
```

```
(('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
 ('an', 'bn', 'cn'))
```

#### EXPLANATION

1. The unpacking operator allows you to unpack the list into the sublists, and passes them as individual parameters to `zip`, as it expects the same.
2. The `zip` combines the first, second, third ... nth respective elements of each sublist into n tuples object

[image]

3. The tuple converts this zip object converts the overall zip object to a tuple.

---

#### Bonus

Intuitively, this operation resembles taking a transpose of a matrix. This can be seen easily if you convert your list of lists to a numpy array and then take a transpose.

```
import numpy as np

l = [["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]
arr = np.array(l)
transpose = arr.T
transpose
```

```
array([['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
       ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']], dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to generalise your code to more than two elements in the sublists:

```py
ll = [["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]

first_elements = [x[0] for x in ll]
second_elements = [x[1] for x in ll]
...
kth_elements(k) = [x[k] for x in ll]
```

Now we just have to use a list comprehension to iterate on the possible values of `k`:

```py
tt = [[x[k] for x in ll] for k in range(len(ll[0]))]
# [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']]
```

Of course you can get `tt` as tuples instead of lists:

```py
tt = tuple(tuple(x[k] for x in ll) for k in range(len(ll[0])))
# (('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'))
```

Note that python already has a builtin function to iterate on several lists simultaneously, `zip`:

```py
tt = tuple(zip(*ll))
# (('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
headers = [[] for i in range(1, len(ll[0]) + 1)]
for i in ll:
    for e in range(0, len(i)):
        headers[e].append(i[e])
res = tuple(tuple(sub) for sub in headers)
print(res)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.